# Version management in SageMaker

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker

We're currently working with 3 employees in the same notebook-instance, however, since this is a shared workspace this makes version management extra difficult. Is it possible to link aws credentials to your git account from within SageMaker? Or are there any other ways recommended for version management?

Right now we're using a single git account for committing the code from within jupyter terminal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The situation has changed : Git is now [available](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/machine-learning/amazon-sagemaker-notebooks-now-support-git-integration-for-increased-persistence-collaboration-and-reproducibility/) in SageMaker

Answer (score 0):

Currently, Amazon SageMaker don't have any native git support beyond running git commands in the terminal. We are always re-evaluating our backlog of features based on customer requests, so we appreciate the feedback on this feature.

Thank you, 
Amazon SageMaker Team